# 999e3 numerical representation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is 999e3 in matlab = 0.999? Because I am not sure whether e mean exponential or you move the decimal point by 3decimal places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$999e3=999\cdot 10^{3}=999000$$